# Pycharm comparison with None performed with equality operators

Tags: python, pycharm, operators, nonetype

I am using python 3.6 and pycharm.

One of my lines of code says:

```
If oim.sent != None:
```

Pycharm gives the following very strongly worded warning:

> That type of comparisons should always be done with 'is' or 'is not',
>   never the equality operators.

However, I am using this line of code to discern between values which are `None` and values which are `False` - Am i right write this line in this way or is it really true that you should NEVER use equality operators with None?

EDIT:

I misinterpreted the warning. I figured it was instructing me to use `if not oim.sent:` which of course would not discern between `None` and `False` - however, as the answers have pointed out the correct expression would be `if oim.sent is not None:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a warning because you not following python guideline. Your code will run fine. If you want, you should better use :

`if oim.sent is not None:`

Comment: Ahhh - I  didn't think of this - i figured it was instructing me to use `if not oim.sent:`

Answer (score 2):

You can of course use `!= None`, however

```
if oim.sent is not None:
```

is faster, and idiomatic Python so everyone will know that you know what you're doing ;-)

Comment: Ahhh - I  didn't think of this - i figured it was instructing me to use `if not oim.sent:`